# update a QuerySet with a Form or ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset, modelform

I'm trying to update all the values of a queryset with a for, I found this method :

```
queryset = Query.objects.filter(version=XXX)
field1 = ModelForm.cleaned['field1']
...
fieldN = ModelForm.cleaned['fieldN']
queryset.update(['field1'=field1, ... , 'fieldN'=fieldN])
```

but I fell like it's not a very clean method, is there a more efficient one ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it using this method :

in forms.py:

```
 class UpdateAll(forms.Form):
    field_1 = forms.FloatField()
    field_2 = forms.FloatField()
    field_3 = forms.FloatField()
```

in views.py :

```
 def update_all(request):
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(filter=filter)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = UpdateAll(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             data = form.cleaned_data
             queryset.update(**data)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `update()` method for model objects. you need to add form data manually to your model.

```py
def update_all(request):
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(filter=filter)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = UpdateAll(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             data = form.cleaned_data
             queryset.field_1 = data['field1']
             queryset.field_2 = data['field2']
             queryset.field_3 = data['field3']
```